# Do globally isometric surfaces have the same second fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\phi: S \rightarrow \tilde{S} $ be a global isometry. I am asked to prove that every geodesic in $\tilde{S}$ is the image by $\phi$ of a geodesic in $S$. 
 First, I argued that they have the same curve length functional, and through the uniqueness of geodesics I argued that the geodesic $\tilde{p}\circ w $ was the same as $\phi \circ p\circ w$. But I wasn't satisfied with this reasoning (I am not even sure it is correct). 
Intuitively, if I deform a surface at every point by the same rigid motion, I don't necessarily have the same normal field, but it would merely get rotated, such that $d\tilde{\nu}=d\nu$. And as such the two surfaces would have the same second fundamental form, hence I could show that if one had geodesic curvature zero its inverse image by $\phi$ would also have it. But I don't know how to show that precisely. Any insight?